# how to center images vertical and horizontal in boostrap 4?

Tags: css, html, image, centering, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using the latest bootstrap 4 and have created a div that is 400px to hold images that range in height from 100px to 350px in height.  I am trying to center the image both horizontally and vertically and have managed to center the image horizontally using the following code.

```
<img src="..." class="mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
```

What class do I add to have the image also be centered in the div vertically?

Comment: make it's container flex `d-flex`

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon. In other words, post all of the *relevant* code. Your current code snippet is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Use d-flex on the conatiner, and you can use my-auto on the images for centering on the y axis.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLvmaw1f/10/)

```
<div class="d-flex" style="height: 400px; border: 2px orange solid;"> 
  <img style="height: 300px; width: 300px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/789141/pexels-photo-789141.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" class="mx-auto my-auto d-block" alt="Turtle pic">
  <img style="height: 200px; width: 200px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/789141/pexels-photo-789141.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" class="mx-auto my-auto d-block" alt="Turtle pic">
</div>
```